# LeakCanary Dependency with Cordova - Could not find method debugCompile()

Tags: android, cordova, maven, gradle, memory-leaks

I am not an Android developer and have a build in Cordova I'd like to check for memory leaks using LeakCanary... (I have no idea how the actual Android build environment works and have been picking through this).

For installation, [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) states, "In your build.gradle":

```
 dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
   testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
 }
```

I am receiving the following error after copying and pasting the above into the *build.gradle (Module: android)*:

> 4:41:15 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not find method debugCompile()
>   for arguments [com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5] on
>   object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>              Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

and in the error Log

> Error:(35, 0) Could not find method debugCompile() for arguments [com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Any ideas about how to fix this? I have been researching with limited success.

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some fiddling around, I have LeakCanary working, although I can't speak to whether it's functioning in it's entirety (it runs, and provides some leakage data in my application).

I also don't understand why it wasn't working...

- Use File > Project Structure > Modules: CordovaLib (not "android") >
  Dependencies tab
- Add the following:

> Debug Compile: com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5
>
> Release Compile: com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5
>
> Test Compile: com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5

- build.gradle (Module: CordovaLib) should now have at the very bottom:

  ```
  dependencies {
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
  }
  ```
- In **CordovaActivity.java**:

  ```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
        // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
        // You should not init your app in this process.
         return;
  }
  LeakCanary.install(getApplication());
  ...
  }
  ```

I believe it should now work.

Interesting note is that it did seem like Ionic/Cordova has very minimal leakage if I installed LeakCanary correctly (3.2 kb) with switching screens, rotating phone, backing in and out of app.

Comment: where will i find the CordovaActivity.java , i mean the location of file in the cordova project